# MSSQL backup file does not list any databases within it

Tags: restore, sql-server-2019

A customer sent us a .bak file from a 2019 instance. I was running 2014 (other customers are) and knew that 2019 would not restore to it. So I installed 2022Dev, went into SQLMS, and created a new DB to hold the data.

I then right-clicked the new DB, and selected Tasks->Restore->Database. I selected Device and selected the file. The name of the file appears beside the Device label as expected.

However, the `Database:` combo below the name is empty. I cannot select the DB to restore and the OK button remains greyed out:

[image]

Having never seen this before, I did some poking about here and found some seemingly unrelated posts about permissions, but to be safe I clicked the Unblock and set the permissions to all. No change.

I'm a bit lost here, any suggestions?

Comment: what comes back if you restore [headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-headeronly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) or  [file lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-filelistonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) from that file?

Comment: @ErikDarling - OK, that was useful, I've never had to try this in SQL before. Running either of those returns an error: "Cannot find server certificate with thumbprint '0x44126restclipped'

Comment: The backup is encrypted and you are missing the encryption certificate. You need to `BACKUP CERTIFICATE` from the original, then restore it to `master` on your new machine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I recover a TDE certificate by restoring the MASTER database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34753/can-i-recover-a-tde-certificate-by-restoring-the-master-database)

Comment: @Charlieface - well it answers it, but offers no solution. The certificate in question is located on a customer's cloud server and there's no way in heck we're getting it. The solution is to simply back it up without encryption, and I'm talking them through it now.